# Cannot install Personas in Firefox 3.5.3

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

I install, restart firefox and then... nothing. I've done this twice or thrice. What could the  problem be?

Answer (score 1):

It may be conflicting with some of the addons you have installed. Try disabling them one by one and see if that makes any difference.

Also try installing it in a clean Firefox profile. If that works, then you know that there is something wrong with your current profile. The easiest way to fix it afterwards is to migrate everything you have in your current profile to the new profile.

To manage profiles, start firefox as "firefox.exe -profilemanager".

Answer (score 0):

You should reboot your computer once to see if that makes a difference. If not, make sure you're not in private browsing mode. You can turn it off under Tools.